# How do I convert a csv to a binary file with a bash command?

Tags: bash, csv, binaryfiles

I have a `csv` file which is just a simple comma-separated list of numbers. I want to convert this `csv` file into a binary file (just a sequence of bytes, with each interpreted number being a number from the `csv` file).

The reason I am doing this is to be able to import audio data from a spreadsheet of values. In my import (I am using audacity), I have a few formats to choose from for the binary file:

```
Encoding:
Signed 8, 24, 16, or 32 bit PCM
Unsigned 8 bit PCM
32 bit or 64 bit float
U-Law
A-Law
GSM 6.10
12, 16, or 24 bit DWVW
VOX ADPCM

Byte Order:
No endianness
Big endian
Little endian
```

I was moving along the lines of `big endian 32-bit float` to keep things simple. I wanted to keep things as simple as possible, so I was thinking `bash` would be the optimal tool.

Comment: It sounds like this is not a traditional `csv` file where records are grouped into line-delimited entries.  This is a file containing strictly one dimensional data: a series of numerals.  How are the numbers encoding the audio?  That will determine whether you need to transcode the output.

Comment: Between a maximum and minimum not less than can be represented by the binary encoding -- in mine it's currently between -100 and 100 and I can amplify it. I was thinking a float encoding would be easiest to work with, like 32-bit or 64-bit float.

Comment: But it's PCM encoded?

Comment: Yeah, it's PCM encoded, to mean each value represents the 1-dimensional result of `f(x)` where `x==time`, so it's just a list of amplitudes by time. It's written on a spreadsheet program, exported as `csv`. In the program, it's just a column of numbers representing amplitudes and in the `csv` file, it's a list of numbers separated by commas.

Answer (score 6):

> I have a `csv` file which is just a simple comma-separated list of numbers. I want to convert this `csv` file into a binary file [...]
>
> I was moving along the lines of `big endian 32-bit float` to keep things simple.

Not sure how to do it in pure `bash` (actually doubt that it is doable, since float as binary is non-standard conversion).

But here it is with a simple Perl one-liner:

```
$ cat example1.csv
1.0
2.1
3.2
4.3

$ cat example1.csv | perl -ne 'print pack("f>*", split(/\s*,\s*/))' > example1.bin

$ hexdump -C < example1.bin
00000000  3f 80 00 00 40 06 66 66  40 4c cc cd 40 89 99 9a  |?...@.ff@L..@...|
00000010
```

It uses the Perl's [pack function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) with `f` to convert floats to binary, and `<` to convert them into BE. (I have also added the split in case of multiple numbers per CSV line.)

P.S. The command to convert to integers to 16-bit shorts with native endianness:

```
perl -ne 'print pack("s*", split(/\s*,\s*/))'
```

Use `"s>*"` for BE, or `"s<*"` for LE, instead of the `"s*"`.

P.P.S. If it is audio data, you can also check the `sox` tool. Haven't used it in ages, but IIRC it could convert anything PCM-like from literally any format to any format, while also applying effects.

Comment: Useless use of cat: `perl -pe '$_ = pack("f>*", split(/\s*,\s*/))' example1.csv > example1.bin`

Comment: @andlr, Yes, useless. But more readable: input file - in front, output file - at the end.

Comment: You can just use `<input.txt perl -pe 'code' >output.txt`

Comment: @andlrc, that syntax is just crazy. +1

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend Python over `bash`.  *For this particular task*, it's simpler/saner IMO.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import array

with open('input.csv', 'rt') as f:
    text = f.read()
    entries = text.split(',')
    values = [int(x) for x in entries]
    # do a scalar here: if your input goes from [-100, 100] then
    #   you may need to translate/scale into [0, 2^16-1] for
    #   16-bit PCM
    # e.g.:
    #   values = [(val * scale) for val in values]

with open('output.pcm', 'wb') as out:
    pcm_vals = array.array('h', values) # 16-bit signed
    pcm_vals.tofile(out)
```

You could also use [Python's `wave` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html#module-wave) instead of just writing raw PCM.

Here's how the example above works:

```
$ echo 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 > input.csv
$ ./so_pcm.py
$ xxd output.pcm
0000000: 0100 0200 0300 0400 0500 0600 0700       ..............
```

`xxd` shows the binary values.  It used my machine's native endianness (little).